# Laravel - Views - router() doesn't work or I just dumb

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my web.php

```
Route::get('read/{book_id}/{part_id}', 'BookPartController@show')->name('read');
```

And this is the Views

```
<a href="{{ route('read', [$part->book_id, $part->part_id]) }}">
```

I wanna expect for the result is `mysite.com/read/808/121`, though the result is this `mysite.com/read/808`

Comment: what is a `$part->part_id` ??

Comment: have value in `$part->part_id`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], with emphasis on Complete. Without your inputs, outputs, and expected outputs, it will be difficult to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: The values of both is integer.

Comment: They should be named $data->book_id & $data->part_id but, I'm too lazy to change em.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way to do it:

```
<a href="{{ route('read', ['book_id' => $part->book_id, 'part_id' => $part->part_id]) }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, adding the keys to the array:

```
<a href="{{ route('read', 
       ['book_id' => $part->book_id, 'part_id' => $part->part_id]) }}">
```

Comment: why `key added` add reason for this